# Non-social connotation of "marginalize"

Tags: single-word-requests

Can the word "marginalize" be used to mean "to put something on the margin" as opposed to the usual meaning of "to exclude someone from a social group"?

I'm trying to think of a verb or adjective to describe something being put on the fringe of a document, something more concise than "put on the margin".

I've come across the phrase "to dock (something)", as in "dock one's pay", but that seems somewhat informal to me. (I might be wrong about that.)

Comment: How is _dock_ even related? When you dock someone's pay, you're not paying them, it has nothing to do with putting it in the margin of a document.

Comment: Oh I was under the impression it meant to put off to the side, like the way "docking a boat" puts it off to the side of body of water. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: There's a noun, scholion, but it's rare, and probably only used for a note in the margin of an ancient document.

Comment: Dock for a boat and dock someones pay are from unrelated etymologies neither of which mean put to the side. As a newer term used in computer language, though, to "dock" something, such as a toolbar usually puts it along the edge of the screen. This is specific to computer interfaces, though.

Comment: Not a single word (although a bit shorter than “put on the margin”), but marginal entries, such as marginal satisfactions of mortgages and updates to some jurisdiction’s birth certificates/l'état civil (Civil status) acts/documents are  “noted marginally” or “entered marginally” on the original documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use to  [footnote](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/footnote):

> a to add a footnote or footnotes to (a text, statement, etc.); annotate.

The Free Dictionary

Though the original meaning of *marginalize*  was *to make notes on the margin*, the current meaning is mainly related to  a social context:

- [Marginalize](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=marginalize&allowed_in_frame=0)  (v.) : (Etymology)

> - ***1832, "to make marginal notes," from [marginal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=marginal&allowed_in_frame=0) + -ize***. The meaning "force into a position of powerlessness" attested by 1929.

- [Marginalize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marginalized) :

> - To relegate or confine to a lower or outer limit or edge, as of social standing.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Footnotes usually refer to comments placed at the bottom of a page, does the same go for things at the top of a page? Or do we call those headnotes or something?

Comment: To footnote, as per its definition, to annotate.  I think it may be taken to mean to add a marginal note, not necessarily a footnote.

Answer (score 0):

*a verb or adjective to describe something being put on the fringe of a
document, something more concise than "put on the margin".*

**comment**

This is both a noun and a verb.  Example:

> I am sending you a Track Changes version, with comments explaining my proposed edits.

Note that in MS Word, the comments normally appear in the right-hand margin.  I believe Google Docs does this too.